# Cannot receive multicast frames

Tags: networking, multicast

I'm bringing up a new machine and it cannot receive multicast frames for some reason.

Everything else about the network seems to work fine.

Even multicast frame seems to get out fine because I can start `avahi-daemon` and on startup I can see multicast going out on another computer on the same switch.

I have this which seems odd:

```
$ cat /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/0000:58:00.0/net/enp88s0/statistics/multicast
0
```

Also on `tcpdump` I get broadcast but no multicast:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -i enp88s0 -n multicast
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on enp88s0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
14:04:02.076411 IP 192.168.2.56.9999 > 255.255.255.255.9999: UDP, length 29
14:04:17.839828 IP 192.168.2.15.9999 > 255.255.255.255.9999: UDP, length 29
14:04:18.013897 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.2.14 tell 192.168.2.15, length 46
14:04:21.826386 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.2.135 tell 192.168.2.135, length 46
14:04:26.014544 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.2.144 tell 192.168.2.144, length 46
14:04:31.272095 IP 192.168.2.55.9999 > 255.255.255.255.9999: UDP, length 29
...
```

Any idea where this could be filtered?

Comment: I think I on to something with this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1906418?comments=all

Comment: It's fine that you bring up your hidden Machine, but why you are not telling us the specs, and in case of Virtualization, which has been used. Or is it Top Secret? :-)

Comment: It's a Tiger Canyon Intel NUC 11 Pro NUC11TNKi5, more info in available in the launchpad bug report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have much detail since I basically bruteforced the solution but it seems to be a driver issue.

The computer hardware is the following:

```
Tiger Canyon
Intel NUC 11 Pro NUC11TNKi5
Ethernet Controller i225-LM
```

The network driver used is `igc`.

The problem appears on:

```
ubuntu-20.04.2-live-server-amd64
5.4.0-77-generic #86-Ubuntu
```

The problem is fixed on the following Ubuntu Server version:

```
ubuntu-21.04-live-server-amd64
5.11.0-25-generic #27-Ubuntu
```

Comment: dont forget to accept your answer, else we will think about in 10 years still to solve this